# Building release version of a project fails to generate files in the release folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, build

I have a project that I have been working on and am closing to release it. With Visual Studio 2010 and .net 4.0, the project fails to generate files and place them in the Release folder even though these are set in the project properties. What are the correct steps here, what could I be missing?

Comment: how are you building your solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the properties page of the project being built. Select the 'Build' tab. In the 'Output' section, verify the output path is set to where you want it to go. (Sorry for the bad screen, but it should get the idea across.)

[image: Project Properties]

Comment: Hi Cloggins, I can confirm this is set to bin\Release however the built binaries still end up in the bin\Debug folder. How can I make sure the built binaries are the actual release versions? That is actually the thing I'm after. How do I check to see if the built binary is a release binary that doesn't contain all the debugging works inside.. Thanks in advance and thanks for your response so far.

Comment: There are two default configs created with a solution: Debug and Release. It sounds like you still have the build configuration set to 'Debug'. The MSDN page for setting the active config is here: [How to: Set Debug and Release Configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx). Remember to verify both configurations have the correct output path. These default to bin\Debug and bin\Release.